# Listing the title of created items in a choice field of another item in plone

Tags: python, plone

I have a problem with my Plone item I cannot solve. 'Car' is supposed to create a list of all instances of 'Colour'.
All 'Colour' instances are in a given container. I cannot make it static because I want to add more 'Colour' instances in the future.
I tried selecting each item in my container and add it to my vocabularylist. I only need the id/title of my object, but I always end up with a giant stacktrace of failures.
In the end I want to choose a colour out of the given instances on creating a new 'Car' instance similar to a dropdown.
I have read the docs but cannot find a solution and this is my best idea.
I am also not a python programmer and this is my first plone project. I can add the complete failure list later if you need it.

I appreciate every bit of help. Thank you.

````
 ```colour= schema.Choice(
       title=u"Colour",
       description=u"Paintjob",
        vocabulary=givecolour(),
        required=False
    )

    @provider(IContextSourceBinder)
        def givecolour():
        colourlist = self.context.portal_catalog(path={"query" : "/madb-entw/it/colourcontainer", "depth" : 1})
        list = []
        i = 0

        for colour in colourlist:
            list.append(
                    SimpleVocabulary.createTerm(
                        colourlist.[i].getObject().id
                    )
            )
            i += 1

        return SimpleVocabulary(list)```
````

Comment: Please ask Plone questions in our forum, https://community.plone.org where more people will see them and be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always add your traces, so that we can help you better.
There is also the official community.plone.org forum, where are more people can help you.

I recommend you to use the [plone.api](http://api.plone.org/) to find your objects, this is a bit easier and well doumented.

something like this:

```
from plone import api
color_brains = api.content.find(context=api.content.get(path='/madb-entw/it/colourcontainer'), depth=1, portal_type='Color')
# no need to do getOject() here, get the id/title directly from the catalog brain
colors = [(color.id, color.Title) for color in color_brains]
```

One note to your query:

> colourlist = self.context.portal_catalog(path={"query" :
>   "/madb-entw/it/colourcontainer", "depth" : 1})

Path has to be absolute, which means it includes the Plone site id and this can be different in another Plone site.
So an absolute path is not a good idea here, better get the portal object and traverse your path relative from there.
If madb-entw is your Plone site id:

```
portal.restrictedTraverse('it/colourcontainer')
```

or better as above, use plone.api.content.get(path='/it/colourcontainer')
Which is cleaner and easier.